# How to switch displaying widgets by each tapping

Tags: flutter, dart, setstate, flutter-listview, gesturedetector

I want to implement a feature that lets users change information about the `items` by tapping each item card.

[image]

By default, users can see the `price` of the items. When tapping an item card, the user can see the `detail` of the item. When tapping the same card one more time, then the user will see the `price` of the item.
I am thinking about using `GestureDetector` and switching the widgets inside `onTap`, but my implementation doesn't work and I can't come up with a solution.

When I write `ItemInfo itemInfo = ItemInfo.price;` outside of the `buildItemCards` method, switching the displaying widgets works, but **every** card's display changes.
How can I switch the `price` and `detail` by tapping **each** item card?

`Item`'s model:

```dart
class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
  int price;
  String detail;

  Item({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    required this.detail,
  });
}
```

```dart
class SwitchWidgetsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const SwitchWidgetsScreen({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SwitchWidgetsScreen> createState() => _SwitchWidgetsScreenState();
}

List<Item> items = [
  Item(id: 1, name: 'Apple', price: 2, detail: 'Juicy.'),
  Item(id: 2, name: 'Banana', price: 1, detail: 'Sweet.'),
  Item(id: 3, name: 'Chocolate', price: 3, detail: 'Bitter.'),
];

enum ItemInfo {
  price,
  detail,
}

class _SwitchWidgetsScreenState extends State<SwitchWidgetsScreen> {
  Widget buildItemCards(Item item) {
    ItemInfo itemInfo = ItemInfo.price;

    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (itemInfo == ItemInfo.price) {
            itemInfo = ItemInfo.detail;
          } else {
            itemInfo = ItemInfo.price;
          }
        });
      },
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(item.name),
          subtitle: itemInfo == ItemInfo.price
              ? Text('Price: ${item.price}G')
              : Text(item.detail),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Items'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return buildItemCards(items[index]);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are trying to change each item separately, but using single variable to control the list. So once the value changes, the full list get changes. You can create another list to control the list or include a variable on model class.

With another list to control text.

```dart
class _SwitchWidgetsScreenState extends State<SwitchWidgetsScreen> {
  List<ItemInfo> infoTypes =
      List.generate(items.length, (index) => ItemInfo.price);
  Widget buildItemCards(int index) {
    Item item = items[index];
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (infoTypes[index] == ItemInfo.price) {
            infoTypes[index] = ItemInfo.detail;
          } else {
            infoTypes[index] = ItemInfo.price;
          }
        });
      },
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(item.name),
          subtitle: infoTypes[index] == ItemInfo.price
              ? Text('Price: ${item.price}G')
              : Text(item.detail),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Items'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return buildItemCards(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Or adding variable or extending Item class

```dart
class Item {
  int id;
  String name;
  int price;
  String detail;
  ItemInfo itemInfo;

  Item(
      {required this.id,
      required this.name,
      required this.price,
      required this.detail,
      this.itemInfo = ItemInfo.price});
}


class _SwitchWidgetsScreenState extends State<SwitchWidgetsScreen> {
  Widget buildItemCards(int index) {
    Item item = items[index];
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        setState(() {
          if (items[index].itemInfo == ItemInfo.price) {
            items[index].itemInfo = ItemInfo.detail;
          } else {
            items[index].itemInfo = ItemInfo.price;
          }
        });
      },
      child: Card(
        child: ListTile(
          title: Text(item.name),
          subtitle: items[index].itemInfo == ItemInfo.price
              ? Text('Price: ${item.price}G')
              : Text(item.detail),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Items'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: items.length,
        itemBuilder: (_, index) {
          return buildItemCards(index);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I prefer using final variable with copyWith method.

Comment: Thank you so much! The issue has been resolved.

Comment: Glad to help, you can more on [codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/first-flutter-app-pt2#0)